# How do I make parallel HTTP requests in Perl, and receive them back in order?

Tags: perl, http, parallel-processing

Using Perl, I'm looking for a simple way to perform a handful of HTTP requests in parallel, where I get responses back in the same order I sent them after they complete, e.g.:

```
my ($google, $perl) = foobar(GET => 'http://www.google.com/',
                             GET => 'http://www.perl.org/');
```

Is there a module I should be looking at?

I know I can do the bookkeeping by hand, but I feel spoiled after being able to do this using [jQuery's `when` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), and I'd love to have as simple a solution using Perl.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FWIW: I just tried to get LWP::Parallel working for the last two hours and have been pulling my hair out.  I do *NOT* recommend LWP::Parallel at all.  It seems very buggy and the API as well as the documentation are lacking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
use threads;
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my @threads;
for my $url ('http://www.google.com/', 'http://www.perl.org/') {
   push @threads, async { $ua->get($url) };
}

for my $thread (@threads) {
   my $response = $thread->join;
   ...
}
```

The best part is that the parent doesn't wait for all requests to be completed. As soon as the right request is completed, the parent will unblock to process it.

---

If you used [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) or something else where you can't wait for a specific child, you can use the following code to order the results:

```
for my $id (0..$#urls) {
   create_task($id, $urls[$id]);
}

my %responses;
for my $id (0..$#urls) {
   if (!exists($responses{$id})) {
      my ($id, $response) = wait_for_a_child_to_complete();
      $responses{$id} = $response;
      redo;
   }

   my $response = delete($responses{$id});
   ...
}
```

Comment: how about a Parallel::ForkManager example too?

Comment: @ysth, The point of P::FM is to work with a fixed-size pool of workers. That's good for sharing CPU. In this case, the OP wants as many workers as possible as all will be sleeping waiting for IO. (If you want processes instead of threads, change `use threads;` to `use forks;`.)

Comment: @ysth, Added an ordering algorithm you could use with P::FM.

Comment: Is there any option to limit threads ( to 200 ) if there is more than 1000 $urls?

Comment: @ovntatar, Yes, but you should consider using Net::Curl::Multi.

Answer (score 11):

I am a fan of [Mojo](http://p3rl.org/Mojo)!
From the [Mojo::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) documentation:

```
use Mojo;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
# Parallel requests
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->max_redirects(5);
my $delay = Mojo::IOLoop->delay;
for my $url ('http://www.google.com/', 'http://www.perl.org/') {
  $delay->begin;
  $ua->get($url => sub {
    my ($ua, $tx) = @_;
    $delay->end($tx->res->dom);
  });
}
my @responses = $delay->wait;
print join "\n", @responses
```

Enjoy!

**EDIT**

Btw. you do not have to process the responses at the end, you may do it in between:

```
# ...
$ua->get($url => sub {
    my ($ua, $tx) = @_;
    $delay->end(1);
    # process $tx->res here
});
# ...
$delay->wait;
```

Comment: I have an entry just like this for the [Perl Advent Calendar](http://perladvent.org) this year, although I don't know which day it will be on.

Comment: @brian d foy, In esskar's solution, the parent waits much longer than needed before starting to process responses. Can that be fixed simply?