# Thread "tagging" in Perl for async HTTP request

Tags: multithreading, perl, http

I know there are other classes I can use, however I want to use LWP.  The accepted answer here ([How do I make parallel HTTP requests in Perl, and receive them back in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372723/how-do-i-make-parallel-http-requests-in-perl-and-receive-them-back-in-order)) does what I want however I need to "tag" the threads so that I can match the request with the response.  I have modified the code to the following:

```
#Setup and query the DB:

#hold all response\id pairs
my @response_bundles; 
while (my @row = $query->fetchrow_array()) {
                my $id = $row[0];
                my $url = $row[1];

                push @threads, async {
                        my @container_hash;
                        $container_hash[0] = @row;
                        $container_hash[1] = $ua->get($url); 

                        push @response_bundles, @container_hash;
                };
}       

#Once this loop terminates all threads are done
for my $thread (@threads) {
                $thread->join;
}

#Since all threads are completed we can now sort through the response bundles
for my $response_bundle (@response_bundles) {
                print "test\n";
}
```

My goal is to kick off a bunch of HTTP requests and store their ($id, $response) pair in an array.  I push them all into an async process and the sub in async{} SHOULD be doing this (but it's not).  I loop through the thread array and once that is complete all threads should be done.  I then go through my bundle and do things however the "print test" is never firing.  Am I thinking about this wrong?

EDIT:

Per the comment I tried returning the value but this does not work either

```
while (my @row = $query->fetchrow_array()) {
                my $id = $row[0];
                my $url = $row[1];

                push @threads, async {
                        my @container_hash;
                        $container_hash[0] = @row;
                        $container_hash[1] = $ua->get($url); 

                        return @container_hash;
                };
}       

#Once this loop terminates all threads are done
for my $thread (@threads) {
                my @container;
                @container = $thread->join;
                print $container[1];
}
```

Comment: Threads run in a different interpreter and don't share data, unless a variable is explicitly marked as shared. You can return values from a thread, and collect them at the `$thread->join`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment.  I did what you stated but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the data you need from your thread so main program can process it:

```
while (my @row = $query->fetchrow_array()) {
                my $id = $row[0];
                my $url = $row[1];

                push @threads, async {
                        my @container_hash;
                        $container_hash[0] = \@row; #I think you need this
                        $container_hash[1] = $ua->get($url); 

                        return \@container_hash; #and here we return reference to our data
                };
}       

#Once this loop terminates all threads are done
for my $thread (@threads) {

                my $container = $thread->join;
                print $container->[1], "\n"; #this is a reference that's why we use ->
}
```