# Perl max limit of threading for parallel requests

Tags: multithreading, perl

Is there any option to limit parallel running threads. In example I have following code:

```
use threads;
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my @threads;
# if @threads < 200
for my $url (@URL_LIST) {
   push @threads, async { $ua->get($url) };
}
# if @threads <= 200
for my $thread (@threads) {
   my $response = $thread->join;
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to create script to proceed only 200 parallel requests if @URL_LIST including more than 10000 urls! But unfortunately the script get an info at the end that more then 20 threads unfinished. Any ideas what the solution should be?

Comment: Maybe you can just use https://metacpan.org/release/ParallelUserAgent ?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of spawning a thread to handle each single URL, perhaps you should spawn a constant number of worker threads that pull URLs from a Thread::Queue object and dump results into another such queue.  When the URL queue empties, the worker threads can then end themselves, and you're left processing the results queue...

Comment: Note that the OP previously mentioned that the responses should be collected in the same order as their corresponding requests were placed.

Answer (score 2):

You previously asked this question in a comment to question about collecting the responses in the same order as the requests were placed, and the code you posted was copied from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8373094/589924) to that question. As such, I presume this is what you want as well.

---

What follows isn't the most efficient solution since there's no thread reuse, but it makes it easy to collect the responses in the order you desire.

```
use threads;
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my @urls = ...;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my @threads;
for (1..200) {
   last if !@urls;
   my $url = shift(@urls);
   push @threads, async { $ua->get($url) };
}

while (@threads) {
   my $thread = shift(@threads);
   my $response = $thread->join;

   if (@urls) {
      my $url = shift(@urls);
      push @threads, async { $ua->get($url) };
   }

   ...
}
```

---

By using the worker model, you can reuse threads to avoid the time it takes to start them up. This also collects the responses in the order you desire.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

my $request_q  = Thread::Queue->new();
my $response_q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @threads;
push @threads, async {
   my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
   while (my $url = $request_q->dequeue()) {
      $response_q->enqueue([ $url, $ua->get($url) ]);
   }
};

$request_q->enqueue($_) for @urls;
$request_q->end();

my %responses;
for my $url (@urls) {
   while (!$responses{$url}) {
      my ($response_url, $response) = @{ $response_q->dequeue() };
      $responses{$response_url} = $response;
   }

   my $response = delete($responses{$url});
   ...
}

$_->join for @threads;
```

Comment: many thanks again, I will test and let you know about the results!